# Animating the view

Tags: ios

I am adding a subView to my superview.It should come on screen with animations.

**Code:**

```
HomeListingView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,300 , 300+190)];   
[HomeListingView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 delay:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{

    [scrollSell addSubview:HomeListingView]; //scrollsell is the object of UIScrollView

}completion:^(BOOL finished){

    NSLog(@"Done");

}];
```

Am I doing something wrong here. Or is there another method to animate?

Comment: you have to set frame in side the animation block.

Comment: I did that but that was also not working.@iBhavin

Comment: so... let start the the beginning: __what would you like to animate?__ adding a subview is not an animatable procedure... so actually your concept is completely wrong here.

Comment: Yes you are right @holex. But I did the animations. Because this was already on my scroll bar. I just had to change the frame. In this case it is working. I  deleted the `memory allocations` and `adding subView` code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to move `HomeListingView` onto the screen, change the code to something like:

```
    HomeListingView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-300, -300 + 190, 300 , 300+190)];  // Create view with frame initially off screen
    [HomeListingView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [scrollSell addSubview:HomeListingView]; //scrollsell is the object of UIScrollView

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 delay:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{

       HomeListingView.frame = CGRectMake(10,10,300 , 300+190)];  // Change the frame to move it on screen

    }completion:^(BOOL finished){
        NSLog(@"Done");
     }];
```

Comment: Yes! I did  something like this and it is working @bobnoble

Comment: I'm not a big fan of animating the `frame` because of performance issues, why isn't the `center` enough being animated in this case?

Comment: @holex animating by updating the `center` would work just as well - just started with what the OP was working on and update that. What information do you have that using `center` improves performance vs `frame`?

Comment: when you update the `frame` property the `–drawRect:` and `–drawLayer:inContext:` methods are invoked explicitly; opposite to updating the `center` property when that such extra resource-sensitive procedure won't happen.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way :

```
    HomeListingView =[[UIView alloc]init];
    [HomeListingView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [self.sclCeel addSubview:HomeListingView]; //scrollsell is the object of UIScrollView

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 delay:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
        HomeListingView.frame  = CGRectMake(10,10,300 , 300+190); // Set your view frame here.
    }completion:^(BOOL finished){
        NSLog(@"Done");
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

In animation block we need to change frame as per animation effect, you done wrong thing please see it

```
UIView * view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
    [self.view addSubview:view];
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];


    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                     animations:^{
                         view.frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x-25, view.frame.origin.y-25, view.frame.size.width+50, view.frame.size.height+50);
                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                     }];
```